# ownCloud - Adds user to group by API

Tags: http-post, owncloud

How add user to group by API in Owncloud ?

In the [tutorial](http://www.multiclinic.com.br/owncloud/core/doc/admin/configuration_user/user_provisioning_api.html#users-addtogroup) says the following:

http://owncloud.mydomain.com/ocs/v1.php/cloud/users/myUser/groups -d groupid="admin"

But, its parameter -d not work, It happens the following error :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ocs>
 <meta>
  <status>failure</status>
  <statuscode>999</statuscode>
  <message>Invalid query, please check the syntax. API specifications are here: http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/open-collaboration-services. DEBUG OUTPUT:
</message>
 </meta>
 <data/>
</ocs>
```

Answer (score 0):

ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" , worked for me.